# react-native run-ios TypeError: invalid data

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to run react-native on my machine. I'm using elementaryOS which is based on Ubuntu 14.04. I create base app with

```
react-native init hello_world
```

then I try to run this as ios app:

```
react-native run-ios
```

this returns me following error:

```
mateusz@mateusz-L702X:~/hello_world $ react-native run-ios
Found Xcode project hello_world.xcodeproj
/home/mateusz/hello_world/node_modules/promise/lib/done.js:10
      throw err;
      ^

TypeError: invalid data
    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:625:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:482:20)
    at _runIOS (runIOS.js:62:19)
    at runIOS.js:24:5
    at tryCallTwo (/home/mateusz/hello_world/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
    at doResolve (/home/mateusz/hello_world/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:200:13)
    at new Promise (/home/mateusz/hello_world/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:66:3)
    at Array.runIOS (runIOS.js:23:10)
    at Object.run (/home/mateusz/hello_world/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js:87:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:88:7)
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build react-native iOS app in Mac only. Using Linux you will not be able to build iOS. Mostly error is related to that.